# Testing blackboxed APIs in JS/Vue with jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

Well, I have an interesting case...

I'm trying to test a Vuex action that uses the Okta SDK to log in a User. Nothing special there. But at the testing level, I'm stuck trying to catch the idea. I mean, I just want to know if the functions have been called, not anything else, here the code:

The service:

```js
const signIn = async ({ username, password }) => {
  const response = await authClient.signIn({ username, password })
  if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
    const tokens = await authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt({
      responseType: 'id_token',
      sessionToken: response.sessionToken
    })
    authClient.tokenManager.add('idToken', tokens.tokens.idToken)
    return response
  }
}
```

The action:

```
async logIn({ commit }, { username, password }) {
  const loginData = await signIn({ username, password })
  commit(mutationTypes.setUserData, {
    ...loginData.user.profile
  })
}
```

The test:

```js
const authClient = {
  signIn() {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve())
  },
  token: {
    getWithoutPrompt() {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve())
    }
  },
  tokenManager: {
    add() {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve())
    }
  }
}

jest.mock('authClient', () => authClient)

it('Auth -> actions.signIn', async () => {
  const commit = jest.fn()
  const username = 'user'
  const password = 'pass'
  await actions.signIn({ commit }, { username, password })

  expect(authClient.signIn).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(authClient.token.getWithoutPrompt).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(authClient.tokenManager.add).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```